# Is the 10GB shared capacity workspace storage limit for compressed or uncompressed data, and is it per user or per workspace?

Tags: powerbi

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-manage-your-data-storage-in-power-bi#shared-capacity-limits

For workspaces in shared capacity, There is a per-workspace storage limit of 10 GB.

Also the dataset limit is 1GB - I believe that the dataset's 1GB limit is based on compressed data (1GB post compression). Is the workspace 10GB limit based on compressed or uncompressed data?

Is the 10GB workspace capacity limit per user or per workspace?

Answer (score 2):

It is both, the workspace does have a 10GB capacity limit. And the user has a 10GB limit for their 'My Workspace'. The total capacity of all the workspaces is 10GB * the number of pro licenses. So you can have users creating App Workspaces and deploying datasets to those, and it does not affect their My Workspace.

For example: 10 PBI Pro Licenses = 100GB of total capacity of the tenant.
So one user who is a developer, has created 20 reports each with 1GB of dataset size (20GB in total). These will have to be split across at least 2 App Workspaces.